# Azure users roles and user profile management

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-membership

I have a windows azure  application already running.(testing phase). Currently I use ACS authentication. users can log on with their windows live-ID. and this is all. no authorisation for now. I need to authorise users with different roles. plus I need also users to log on with different Identity providers like gmail and facebook. I have the idea to store profile information in a table (eg. Idp as partition key and User ID(which I get from the provider)as RowKey.)

Now I have have no idea how to give different roles and how to start? can any body give me a clear tutorial or just an idea how to begin with?

tnx

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the **BlobShare** application. This isn't a tutorial, but it's a complete application showing a few interesting concepts you could use:

> The BlobShare Sample is a simple file sharing application that
>   demonstrates the storage services of the Windows Azure Platform,
>   together with the authentication and ***authorization*** capabilities of
>   Access Control Service (ACS).

http://blobshare.codeplex.com/

Comment: Isn't there any documentation on this?